# Spinner Text do not wrap

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am developing android app in which I used spinner view but text on spinner do not wrapped so please help me on how to achieve this .

Thanks in advance[image]

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                scondDD_ItemName) {

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
                        .getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
                return v;
            }

            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

                Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
                        .getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

                return v;
            }
        };

        adapter_state1
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter_state1);
```

Comment: post some code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a layout with root element a `TextView` and use `android:singleLine="false"`. Then use this layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item_1`.